# How to remove dryer from top of stacked washer/dryer in small closet?

Tags: dryer, appliances, washing-machine, closet

I have a washer and dryer stacked on top of each other in a fairly tight closet,  see picture below.  Due to a couple electrical boxes on one side of the closet, I am unable to slide the units to the side to access the back of the closet.  By climbing on top of the stack I can see that the water hoses are too short to slide the whole unit out of the door, as suggested in this question:
[How to move stacked washer/dryer from closet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/32952/how-to-move-stacked-washer-dryer-from-closet)

There does appear to be enough dryer vent and electrical cord to move just the dryer all the way out of the door.

I have verified that the dryer will come free of the washer by removing a couple screws on the front of the unit.

I'm not strong enough nor large enough to move the 127 lbs of dryer by myself, and due to the space restrictions of the closet I can't see how to get another person in the space to help me with the lift.  Additionally, the width of dryer is 27" while the width of the door at the smallest point is 29.5" which means it would be impossible to carry the unit out the door and have your arms wrapped around the side of the unit.

What is the easiest method of removing the dryer from the top of the washer for servicing?  What tools or devices are recommended to help safety remove the dryer?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you answered your question in the question. Where's the confusion?

Comment: How did they get installed in the first place?

Comment: @isherwood what I was trying to ask is how to safely remove the dryer, I'm not strong enough to lift the unit by myself.  I've edited the question to clarify my question.

Comment: @DoxyLover I'm not sure how they installed it. I've asked myself that question many times.

Comment: Here's a guess: a tall strong person (or 3) with lift straps. Can you potentially wedge something under the dryer to lift it up?

Comment: @ShimonRura I can probably wedge something under the dryer to lift it up.  I measured the width of the dryer and door frame and there is only 2.5" of spare distance; the lift straps would have to be positioned such that your arms are not needed on the side of the unit otherwise your elbows would hit the side of the door frame.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like there is enough room in there to tilt the whole set over.  Which is likely how the installers did it.  Place some thick blankets/moving pads on your floor.  Make sure you put all the screws back so it is secured and tilt the whole unit over out and out the doorway.  You should then be able to maneuver it enough to get all the attachment screws out and separate the two then til the units back upright.  I strongly recommend getting a second set of hands to do this though.

Comment: Good idea!  I am little concerned about the screws that hold the two together not being strong enough to hold the load as it tilts over.  I wonder if I could put a couple straps around the two and wench them together...

Comment: @DakotaD I mean those ratchet straps would certainly work.  The other thing you could do is call the mfr and ask for their support dept and see if they have suggestions or accepted methods for doing this sort of thing because I am sure your situation is far from unique in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a professional service the dryer.  The short answer to my question is there no easy way to move the dryer.  It required significant effort both to remove the dryer and even more effort to reinstall it.

The repair guy's method was basically to have two people and use brute strength.  Even with his size and strength it took a few tries to get the unit back into the closet.

I think the long-term solution is to either replace both stacked units with an all-in-one washer/dryer unit that would intrinsically take less space and allow for easier access to the back panels, or place the washer/dryer stack on a movable cart with longer cabling and hoses that allows the unit to be rolled out the door without first disconnecting it.

**update**

We had a new washer and dryer installed by professionals.  The method they used to access the connections on the back was to have a tall, skinny guy climb over the machine while a second guy moved the stack as necessary to accommodate the first guy. Once the back connections are taken care of, the unit can slide on the drain pan through the door.  Because the drain pan is slightly wider than the door, it was necessary to compress the sides of the pan as it passed through the doorway.

Comment: Your set up concerns me, what happens if one of the water supply hoses bursts and you need to turn the water off in a hurry ?  They do make auto shut offs for washing machine valves that will turn off the valve it detects a leak or water on the floor.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I agree that the setup is less than desirable, however it's not as bad as it may seem to shut off the water valves in back. The picture I posted doesn't show it, but the valves can be accessed on the side using a long rod.  I've been able to turn them off and on this way.  The auto shut off sensor is an excellent idea, I'll keep that in mind as a future improvement.